# Help hint on the following question regarding countable dense set and Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Please help hint on the following question. Thank you!

> Let $E⊆\Bbb{R}^n$ be a measurable set with positive measure, and let $D⊆\Bbb{R}^n$ be a countable dense set. Prove that $|\Bbb{R}^n-⋃_{q∈D} (q+E)|=0$.

Comment: Can you please explain what does $|\mathbb{R}^n - \cup_{q \in D} (q+E)| = 0$ mean?

Comment: @amirbd89 what's there to explain? Okay, using a minus sign for set difference might not be the best idea, but other than that it's pretty clear: It's the Lebesgue measure of the complement (in $\mathbb R^n$) of the union of translates of $E$ by elements of $D$.

Comment: I did not know that $|A|$  means Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show that every point of $\mathbb R^n$ is a point of density of $\bigcup_{q \in D} (q + E)$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. What is a point of density?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For every measurable set $A$ of measure $0 < \mu(A) < \infty$ and $\epsilon >0$ there exists a cube $C$ ( with rational coordinates of the vertices) so that $\mu(C\cap A) \ge (1-\epsilon)\, \mu(C)$.

Assume now that $F\colon = \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \cup{q \in D}(q + E) $ has measure $>0$. Take $C$ and $C'$ cubes of same edge length so that 
$$ \mu(C\cap F) \ge\frac{3}{4} \mu(C) \\
\mu(C' \cap E)  \ge\frac{3}{4} \mu(C')$$

Then for every $q \in D$ we have $\mu((q+C') \cap (q+E))  \ge\frac{3}{4}\mu(q+C')$. Now choose $q \in D$ so that $q+ C'$ so close to $C$ that 
$$ \mu(C\cap (q+ C') \cap F) \ge\frac{2}{3} \mu(C\cap (q+ C')) \\
\mu(C\cap (q+ C') \cap (q+E))  \ge\frac{2}{3} \mu(C\cap (q+ C'))$$

Therefore, $\mu(F \cap (q+E) >0$, contradiction.

$\bf{Added:}$

Here is a justification for the first statement. Consider a family of cubes $(C_n)$ intersecting only along faces so that $\cup C_n \supset A$ and $\sum \mu(C_n) \le  (1+\epsilon) \mu(A)$ ( that by the definition of measure). Then for at least one of them we have $\mu(C_n) \le (1+\epsilon)\mu(C_n \cap A)$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you help explain why "there exists a cube $C$ ( with rational coordinates of the vertices) so that $\mu(C\cap A) \ge (1-\epsilon)\, \mu(C)$" or provide a reference? Thank you!

Comment: @Tony: Added some details.  Note: if it's true for a cube, it has to be true for at least one of the smaller cubes that would divide this cube ( like a density, it has to be higher than the average in at least in one region). That's why you can arrange so the cubes have the same side ( also, we could start with rational sides).